# Update array objects using for-of

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have the following two objects arrays. What I'm trying to do is if the `id` attribute matches, replace the array `x` item with the array `y` item.

I can achieve this easily from a plain-old **for** loop. But I don't understand why my **for-of** loop returns a different result.

```js
let x1 = [{
  id: '1',
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}];

let y1 = [{
  id: '1',
  c: 3,
  b: 2
}];

let x2 = [{
  id: '1',
  a: 1,
  b: 2
}];

let y2 = [{
  id: '1',
  c: 3,
  b: 2
}];



let updateX1 = (x, y) => {

  for (let itemY of y) {

    for (let itemX of x) {

      if (itemY.id === itemX.id) {
        itemX = itemY;
      }
    }
  }

  return x;
}

let updateX2 = (x, y) => {

  for (let i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {

    for (let j = 0; j < x.length; j++) {

      if (y[i].id === x[j].id) {
        x[j] = y[i];
      }
    }
  }

  return x;
}

console.log(updateX1(x1, y1));
console.log(updateX2(x2, y2));
```

Why am I getting two different results for the above two approaches? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You get different results because you are mutating your original arrays, first time for x1 it changes the array then for x2 it changes the array again.

Comment: `for of` makes new variables. You're doing an assignment to that new variable rather than mutating the original array as you are in the `for i`.

Comment: Your problem can be reduced to: `let arr = ["hello"]; arr[0] = "bye"; console.log(arr[0]); let x = arr[0]; x = "asdf"; console.log(arr[0]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reassigning a variable, by itself, will never mutate an existing object, or at least not outside of very strange situations. When you do

```
itemX = itemY;
```

you're just changing the value that the `itemX` variable points to to `itemY`. What was originally `itemX`, and the object from which `itemX` came from, will not be changed. In order to mutate objects, you must always explicitly assign a new value to the *property* of the object, such as with `obj.foo`, `obj['foo']`, or, as in your code, `x[j] = y[i];`.

Answer (score 1):

If what you try to do is actually what you say:

> if the id attribute matches, replace the array x item with the array y
>   item

Then instead of nested loops you could use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```js
const x = [
  { id: 1, name: 'should be replaced by y' },
  { id: 2, name: 'not replaced' },
];
const y = [
  { id: 1, name: 'this is from y' },
  { id: 3, name: 'not not used' },
];

const newX = x.map((xItem) => {
  const fromY = y.find((yItem) => yItem.id === xItem.id);
  return fromY ? fromY : xItem;
});
console.log(newX);
```

If mutating is what you're after then you can use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) as that is more appropriate for side effects

```js
const x = [
  { id: 1, name: 'should be replaced by y' },
  { id: 2, name: 'not replaced' },
];
const y = [
  { id: 1, name: 'this is from y' },
  { id: 3, name: 'not not used' },
];
//mutate x
x.forEach((xItem, index) => {
  const fromY = y.find((yItem) => yItem.id === xItem.id);
  x[index] = fromY ? fromY : xItem;
});
console.log(x);
```

Comment: I was wondering about the difference between those two. Anyway thanks for the suggestion.